# Convert csv into time series using r?

Tags: r

I have a csv file in the following format:

```html
day temp    DO
           2019-01-15 00:06:00  16.947  8.45
           2019-01-15 00:21:00  16.862  8.429
           2019-01-15 00:36:00  16.752  8.425
           2019-01-15 00:51:00  16.735  8.379
           2019-01-15 01:06:00  16.65   8.38
           2019-01-15 01:21:00  16.608  8.358
           2019-01-15 01:36:00  16.523  8.354
```

I want to convert above data into time-series format and output should look like :

```html
    temp    DO
           2019-01-15 00:06:00  16.947  8.45
           2019-01-15 00:21:00  16.862  8.429
           2019-01-15 00:36:00  16.752  8.425
```

I have tried the following codes

```
z<- read.zoo(text = "GPP.csv", header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M")
```

But what I get is "GPP.csv" and no data. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: try `format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: Have you tried to load your .csv file using `read.csv()` and then convert the column in `POSIXCT` format using, for example, `as.POSIXct()`?

Comment: I am still receiving "NA" in all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following codes works well for me:

data <- read.zoo("filename",
header=TRUE, index.column = 1:2, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="CET",sep=",")